# Feasible way to map server response into Backbone models?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

The server responds with something on the form:

```
{'dates': 
    {'2013.05-17': 
        {'activities': 
            {'activity 1': 
                {time: 0, 'synced': false},
             'activity 2': 
                {time: 5, 'synced': false},
             'activity 3':...
            },...
     },
     '2013.05-18':
        { ...}, ...},
 'id': id}
```

I currently put everything in a single Backbone model, which doesn't seem like the proper way to do it. The examples I've read around the web all use very simple models where there's no nestled structures and the mapping is pretty simple e.g. `{x: 1, y: 2}` being mapped to a coordinate model and so on.

What's the "correct" way to map the above JSON structure to Backbones models/collections?

Comment: Have you tried BackboneRelational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Protostome mentions, Backbone Relational is good for this kind of thing.

However looking at the JSON data that you have used as an example, from my viewpoint you have only one model and collection as follows:

- Activity Model
- Activities Collection

Even though you have a nested set of data you could look at it in a different way which gives you a simple backbone model, for example:

```
var activity = {
    id: "Activity 1"
    time: 0,
    synced: false,
    date: "2013.05-17"
    batchId: id // this corresponds to the id property in your example
}
```

This represent all of the data contained in your complex nested hierarchy more simply, and more importantly suited to the way Backbone works.

If you cannot alter what the server provides you, you could use the Underscore library functions (from memory _.map()) to map the JSON you receive into simple JSON objects ready for use with Backbone.

I am hoping that maybe you can simplify your design by thinking outside the the context of sticking with a hierarchy?

Comment: A very good point. I do have the option of changing the server response. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: I rewrote the complete structure similar to what you suggested and it mapped a lot better to my code. Thank you! :-)